# How to push item to not existing object key

Tags: javascript

I want to create object of arrays but when i run below code it gives

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

How can i push something to not existing array?

```js
const obj = {}

someArray.forEach(key => {
    anotherArray.forEach(key2 => {
        obj[key].push(key2)
    })
})
```

Comment: "*How can i push something to not existing array?*" you cannot. You have to create the array first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `obj` is an empty array , it does not have `key` property. So before pushing you can check if it has the property , if not then you can create and then `push`

```js
const obj = {}

someArray.forEach(key => {
  anotherArray.forEach(key2 => {
    if (!obj[key]) {
      obj[key] = []
    }
    obj[key].push(key2)
  })
})
```